# Axios dividing get function into two

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux, promise, axios, es6-promise

I have a problem with chaining promises using axios:

```
export const get5DayForecast = () => {
    return axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/weatherForecast').then(res => {
        return res;
    }).catch(err => {
        return err;
    });
}; 
export const load5dayForecast = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return get5DayForecast.then(res => {
            dispatch(load5dayForecastSuccess(res.data));
        }).catch(err => {
            throw (err);
        });
    };
```

On the other hand this approach works:

```
export const load5dayForecast = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/weatherForecast').then(res => {
            dispatch(load5dayForecastSuccess(res.data));
        }).catch(err => {
            throw (err);
        });
    };
}
```

It's part of react reducer actions. What am I missing ?

Comment: You probably mean `get5DayForecast()` instead of `get5DayForecast`. But you should be more specific. "*I have a problem*" does not tell anything.

Comment: For your answer - what @str says. In addition ....to propagate an error down a promise chain it must be re-thrown (as in `load5dayForecast()`). Returning a caught error (as in `get5DayForecast()`) will send it down the success path.